# Largest value in a column of ms access and display in a text box VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How to find the largest value in a column of a access table. and displayed in a text box. I give 101 as the default value of the column and the table is empty. I try like this.. But its not working. Code is given below

```
Dim empid As Integer
empid=101
TXTEMPID.Text=empid
getConnect()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT MAX(EMP_ID) FROM EMPLOYEE "
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL, Conn)
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If Reader.Read Then
            empid = CInt(Reader("EMP_ID"))
        End If
        MessageBox.Show(empid)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
    End Try
    TXTEMPID.Text = empid + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my code like this given below.. Its working coooool......

```
 getConnect()
    Conn.Open() 
    Dim str As String
    Dim newNumber As Integer
    str = "SELECT MAX(EMP_ID) AS MAXIMUM FROM EMPLOYEE"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, Conn)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read()
            TXTEMPID.Text = dr("MAXIMUM").ToString
            newNumber = CInt(Val(TXTEMPID.Text))
            If newNumber = 0 Then
                newNumber = 101
                TXTEMPID.Text = CStr(newNumber)
            Else
                newNumber = newNumber + 1
                TXTEMPID.Text = CStr(newNumber)
            End If
        End While
    End If
    Conn.Close()
```

Thank you all for replay and comment my question

Answer (score 1):

If the table is empty then there is no "largest value" because the table contains no values at all.

### Edit

Ah, okay. It sounds like you were tripping over the fact that, for an empty table, expressions like `DMax("EMP_ID","YourTable")` will return `Null`, and `Null + 1` will return `Null`, so how do we get started? You could try something like...

```
Me.txtEMP_ID.Value = Nz(DMax("EMP_ID","YourTable"), 100) + 1
```

...in the `Form Load` event, although I should mention that this type of approach can cause problems is your database is (or will ever become) multi-user.

Comment: i give default value of the column is 101 and i open the table it shows 101 in the field

Comment: @Thanzeem When you open the table in datasheet view it shows you "101" as the default value for a new record, but that new record doesn't exist yet.

Comment: actually i need to display `EMP_ID` in text box initially 101. and when i press Add Button again i want to check the column in table and find the largest `EMP_ID` and display the `EMP_ID + 1` in the text box

Comment: can u give an example please??

Comment: i don't get what is `Nz` and how i write query?

Comment: @Thanzeem I've already given you a code sample. The line of VBA code in my answer will find the maximum `EMP_ID` value, convert a `Null` value to 100 (that's what `Nz()` does), add 1 to the result and put that into a text box named `txtEMP_ID` on your form.

Answer (score 0):

here is the query

```
Select Top 1 MAX(col 2), col1 from Table1 group by col1
```

to get the results you have to perform

```
Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand
Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &    System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\URDataBaseName.mdb"
cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
cnnOLEDB.Open()

cmdOLEDB.CommandText ="Select Top 1 MAX(col 2), col1 from Table1 group by col1"
cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB

txtbox.text = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

ExecuteScalar Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored

Comment: Why is `group by col1` necessary if all they want is the largest value in a single column? (For the moment we'll ignore the fact that the table is empty.)

Comment: becuase using the MAX Aggregate function

Comment: ...but why refer to `col1` at all? `SELECT MAX(col_2) AS foo FROM Table1` should suffice.

Comment: to give him an idea if he wants to get other columns too

Comment: actually i need to display `EMP_ID` in text box initially 101. and when i press Add Button again i want to check the column in table and find the largest `EMP_ID` and display the `EMP_ID + 1` in the text box